# Raspberry Pi Chromium: QR-Code for Whatsapp Web doesn't load

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium, whatsapp

I want to make a python program controlling my browser on my **Raspberry Pi Model B+** using **Raspberry Pi OS**, but am running into a very basic issue. When opening **web.whatsapp.com** on the installed Chromium browser, the QR code used to link one's phone with the web app doesn't load.
[image: the page that should have a qr code]
I have not run into issues on other websites, which is why I belive it has something to do with Whatsapp Web. Research led me to other problems people have when using Whatsapp Web on their Raspberry, but nobody mentioned the QR code not even loading.
Help would be appreciated.